# Getting a portable (gnu) Makefile operate with pattern rules on files in subdirectories matching a regexp

Tags: python-3.x, makefile

I would like to use this Makefile both on Debian and Windows 10.

I have a set of measurements (and keep adding more) and the raw data files go into subdirectories called "measurement-12-Apr-2020" (with the date of the day I took the measurement). On those raw data files I run a series of post processing steps, each encapsulated in its own little tool, creating new output files and building on each other. Those different output files have distinct extensions: .raw for raw data files, .rot for coordinate rotations, .off for offset removal etc. I have pattern rules in my Makefile for those steps. For a few such steps I calculate special transformation matrices, that of course match just their set of data files. Those i call e.g. "transform.calibrate" or "transform.aligne"

So far the Makefile operated in just one directory and I moved the data files manually in and out of their directories.

Now I would like my top level Makefile with its pattern rules to operate on the data in the subdirectories.

How do i get it to look at the files in directories that match the "measurement-DATE" pattern? And how do i get the pattern rules to operate on one data set, using the local transformation files?

Here is my code with a recursive makefile. I would like a non-recursive makefile without the ugly 
`BIN := ${CURDIR}/../bin` and half-good variable usage and content when the Makefile runs in the subdirectories. Furthermore i get an python error 9009 since i switched to the subdirs and the bin-directory (which is most likely related, but an other problem, really.).

```
ifdef OS
   RM = del /Q
   FixPath = $(subst /,\,$1)
   COPY = copy
   PYTHON = "c:\Users\Blah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"
else
   ifeq ($(shell uname), Linux)
      RM = rm -f
      FixPath = $1
   endif
   COPY = cp
   PYTHON = python
endif

.PHONY: test default
.DEFAULT_GOAL := default

# This is for running inside PyCharm
export PATH:=${CURDIR}/venv/bin:${PATH}

# file endings:
# raw
# calibrate  file ending for transformation matrix
# cal calibrated data file
# ali alignement transformation
# rot rotated, aligned sensors
# off offset removed
# pha phase and

measurement_dirs :=  $(filter %/, $(wildcard messung-*/))
BIN := ../bin

DIRS_CMD = $(foreach subdir, $(measurement_dirs), make-rule/$(subdir))
# Makefiles = $(foreach subdir, $(measurements_dirs), $(subdir)Makefile )

default: transform.align transform.calibrate $(wildcard messung-*.pha)

all: $(DIRS_CMD)
    @echo $(BIN)

transform.calibrate: calibrationsequence.raw
    $(PYTHON) $(BIN)/calculateCalibration.py $<

%.cal: transform.calibrate %.raw
    $(PYTHON) $(BIN)/applyCalibration.py $*.raw

transform.align: calibrationsequence.cal transform.calibrate
    $(PYTHON) $(BIN)/calulateAlignement.py calibrationsequence.cal

%.rot: transform.align %.cal
    $(PYTHON) $(BIN)/applyAlignment.py $*.cal

%.off: %.rot
    $(PYTHON) $(BIN)/clearOffset.py $*.rot

%.pha: %.off
    $(PYTHON) $(BIN)/demodulateSignals.py $*.off

test: test_%.py
    $(PYTHON) pytest -v test

make-rule/%:
    cp Makefile $* && cd $* && make
```

Comment: You say that you move files manually between steps. Do you want to continue doing that, or do you want Make to do it for you?

Comment: I changed the program that generates them, and it creates the directories and puts the files in there. I dont want to move files around, that is error prone.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the sequence implied by your makefile. Which is to be built first, `transform.calibrate: calibrationsequence.cal` or `transform.calibrate`? Each seems to be a prerequisite of the other.

Comment: yes, that was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart of the problem is that two variables are involved and unknown beforehand: the names of the directories and the names of the raw files. Make can handle one variable easily, but struggles with two.

Suppose we have one directory, `messung-12-Apr-2020`, with three raw files `alpha.raw`, `beta.raw` and `calibrationsequence.raw`.

The rule is simple:

```
.PHONY: 12-Apr-2020                                                                                               
12-Apr-2020: messung-12-Apr-2020/apha.pha messung-12-Apr-2020/beta.pha messung-12-Apr-2020/calibrationsequence.pha
    @echo $@ done
```

If we do not know the names of the raw files beforehand, we can derive them:

```
RAW_FILES := $(wildcard messung-12-Apr-2020/*.raw)
PHA_FILES := $(patsubst %.raw,%.pha,$(RAW_FILES))

12-Apr-2020:$(PHA_FILES)
    @echo $@ done
```

If we do not know the name of the directory beforehand, we could use `subst` instead of `patsubst` and put everything into a pattern rule:

```
TARGETS := 12-Apr-2020

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(TARGETS): %: $$(subst .raw,.pha,$$(wildcard messung-%/*.raw))
    @echo $@ done
```

(Note the use of `$$`.) This is safe as long as there is no chance of ".raw" embedded in a file name. There is a safer, more rigorous approach, but it is more complicated; if you need it, let me know in a comment and I will post it.

Now to generate the list of targets:

```
TARGETS := $(patsubst messung-%,%,$(wildcard messung-*))

.PHONY: all $(TARGETS)

all: $(TARGETS)
```

and modify the other pattern rules to be executed from the master directory:

```
%.pha: %.off
    cd $(dir $*); $(PYTHON) $(BIN)/demodulateSignals.py $(notdir $*).off
```

(Clumsy, but effective.) It should be clear how to modify the pattern rules for `%.off`, `%.rot`, `%.cal`, `%/transform.calibrate` and `%/transform.align` the same way.

Comment: how could i automatically filter out the name of the inital phony targets (which are just the date-strings which are part of the directory names like "messung-13-Apr-2020")? Make does not seem to support such string manipulation, does it?

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei: I don't understand. Could you give me an example of what you want to do?